# Как запретить WebView передавать разрешение экрана?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

У меня в проекте есть WebView, я перехожу на сайт, который адаптирован под мобильные устройства, моя задача зайти "как-будто" с компьютера.
Подменяю User-Agent - ничего не выходит. Сайт всё равно перебрасывает на мобильную версию.
Видимо сайт смотрит разрешение экрана / браузера и перекидывает на мобильную версию. Как мне его обмануть ? Как запретить моему WebView (или каким-то заголовкам) отправлять информацию о размерах экрана или подменить их ?

Comment: как вы подменяете User-Agent?

Comment: Вот так:
mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/602.3.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.2 Safari/602.3.12");

Comment: Была у меня такая беда, что смена агента ничего не меняла. И дело было то-ли в кэше, то-ли в куках, уж не помню - попробуйте их чистить перед сменой агента.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
 String newUA= "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
 mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);
```

Comment: Не получается :( Результат тот же. Там в медиа запросах видимо уже перенаправляет на мобильную вёрстку, как "сказать" сайту, что у меня больше разрешение устройства, чтобы он думал, что я с компьютера?)

Comment: @Vertov гляньте [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688030/setting-webview-to-view-desktop-site-and-not-mobile-site/14688100) пару вариантов

Comment: посмотрел) попробовал - не получается) они там пишут про юзер агент все, а мне кажется, что вёрстка с медиа-запросами просто определяет, что ширина экрана маленькая и это не может быть компьютер, поэтому и отображает мобильную версию.
Как дать понять сайту, что у меня большое разрешение ?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
public void setDesktopMode(WebSettings webSettings, final boolean enabled) {

        final String newUserAgent;
        if (enabled) {
            newUserAgent = webSettings.getUserAgentString().replace("Mobile", "eliboM").replace("Android", "diordnA");
        }
        else {
            newUserAgent = webSettings.getUserAgentString().replace("eliboM", "Mobile").replace("diordnA", "Android");
        }

        webSettings.setUserAgentString(newUserAgent);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(enabled);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(enabled);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(enabled);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(enabled);
    }
```

Comment: Нет :( ничего не выходит всё равно показывается мобильная версия

Comment: Поддержку JavaScript включили?

Comment: Да, разумеется) проблема в ширине экрана, медиа-запросы css понимают, что у меня ширина экрана маленькая и отображает мобильную версию. Как мне дать понять сайту, что у меня большое разрешение ?